# Joining two column's components into a single column based on criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below data set and I want to have it joined into a single column like below from two different columns. Here is the data set.

Actual Data set:

```
Station_id |Market  | Households | Over Air

    1      |Houston |2117641     |220221

    2      |Topeka  |182443      |4562

    3      |Columbus |922291     |167671

    3      |Boston   |1200       |13400
```

From the above data set I want to have below result.

```
Station_id  | Market |  Value

    1      | Houston  | 2117641

    2      | Topeka    |  182443

    3      | Columbus  | 167671

    3      | Boston    | 13400
```

please help me how to write the query to get the result. I am using Mysql database.

Thanks & Regards

Arfater Rahman.

Comment: on which criteria do you want to merge two columns?

Comment: Based on which condition

Comment: when Station_id = 1 or 2 then in the Value column should be the number of corresponding Households number but when Station_id =3 then the value column should be the number from Over Air column .

Comment: It's is very difficult to comprehend your sample data above as it does not align in columns

Comment: are you still following this? is it answered?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
CASE
    WHEN Station_id = 3 then `Over Air`
    ELSE `Households` 
END
```

---

based on:

```
Station_id |    Market  | Households | Over Air
1              Houston     2117641     220221
2              Topeka      182443      4562
3              Columbus    922291      167671
3              Boston      1200        13400
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the following query:

```
SELECT Station_id, Market, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Station_id=1 THEN Households 
        WHEN Station_id=2 THEN Households
        WHEN Station_id=3 THEN Over_Air 
    END AS Value
FROM DATASET
```

Comment: @ thanks for your reply i tried with the code but not working.